# How to teach CNN using Keras to recognise objects on a larger image than teaching dataset

Tags: python-3.x, keras, dataset, conv-neural-network

I am not that experienced with Neural Networks and I am currently learning to use Keras and Deeplearning because of the school project.

I have a set of images with size: 1500 x 500

Someone on SO recommended me to cut the image to extract the dataset, so I did using the:

```
image_slicer
```

python3 package. When I removed all images that do not represent an object I am searching for (lines on road) I am left with dataset of images, each with size: 150 x 50.

I would like to teach my Neural Network to recognise these parts on an image 1500 x 500.

What I've done, when trying to teach the CNN for MNIST is this code:

```
cnn.add( Conv2D(30, (5, 5), input_shape = (28, 28, 1), activation = "relu") )
cnn.add( MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)) )
cnn.add( Conv2D(15, (3, 3),  activation = "relu") )
cnn.add( AveragePooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)) )
cnn.add( Flatten() )
cnn.add( Dense(500, activation = "relu") )
cnn.add( Dropout(0.5) )
cnn.add( Dense(10, activation = "softmax") )

cnn.compile( Adam(lr = 0.01), loss = "categorical_crossentropy", metrics = ["accuracy"] )

cnn.fit( X_train, Y_train, epochs = 10, validation_split = 0.1, batch_size = 400, verbose = 1, shuffle = True )
```

But now my dataset images size do not match the image size where I would like to test my Neural Network so I am not sure what to do.

(1) Should I teach CNN on image sizes: input_shape = (150, 50, 1), as my dataset consists of grayscale images 150x50, and then, pass the image of size: 1500 x 500 to CNN (and how, as my input_shape in CNN does not match the image of this size, so the programme would break)?

(2) Also, I would like to draw the regions containing object I am searching for on an image. I trust I would use openCV to display the image and draw Rectangles, but how would I ask CNN to find the regions on a new image containing objects I am searching for as the objects size will not be 150x50, because I am searching for roadlines and they can be longer and narrower than the dataset image size?

I have two more quick questions as well.

(3) Is it possible to "export" the CNN once it has been taught, and then avoid the teaching step next time I run the programme? I would like to say something like:

```
if metrics["accuracy"] >= 0.9:
    # export neural network
```

And after I was to export it using teaching_NN.py, how would I load that network construction and parameters inside search_NN.py?

(4) I am searching only for one type of object and that is the road line (I do not care whether it is segmented line or not). If I were to use binary_crossentropy, I would have two labels 1 and 0, but I only need one of them. Is it okay if I didn't use one of them?

I know this is probably to much to ask, but if anyone could also give me, at least, some pseudo-code, that would be really nice. :)

Comment: are you using a detection network architecture like yolo? If the network is fully convolutional, you can just resize the input, since weights for convolution filters are independent from the input/layer size.

Comment: if you are using a classifier network, you can use sliding window approaches, but they will be slow

Comment: If I were to resize the image from 1500x500 to 150x50, wouldn't I lose the quality needed to find the object as object itself would not be recognisable anymore? I am trying to do something similar to the MNIST code I've left.

Comment: how was the initial 1500*500 been cut to 150*50 ?

Comment: @venkatakrishnan, I've noted in post that I've used py package image_slicer.

Comment: image slicer is the tool. what's the logic behind ?

Comment: @venkatakrishnan, it is. I wouldn't know what magic it does. You specify how many samples of image you want. If you specify, 10 on 1500x500 it would cut out the original image in 10 150x50 images.

Comment: how about passing your test image to it and get the slices and get the prediction  ?

Comment: Yeah, but I do not know what would be coding strategy to do that.